# How to create an xml schema with key/keyrefs for nested elements of the same type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, keyref

I work with some XML files on a regular basis and want to have better validation then a DTD can provide. So I started reading about schemas to see if would help me out. So far I've been able to create something that works almost like I need except for one piece. I want to be able to restrict the attribute of an element to the values of a different attribute of sibling or ancestor elements that are of the same element type. Is this even possible with XML Schema key/keyref constrictions?

I've got a document that looks something like this:

```
<nodeContainer>
    <node name="Table">
    </node>

    <node name="MyHouse">
        <node name="RoomWithDoor">
        </node>
        <node name="DiningRoom" extends="RoomWithDoor">
            <node name="DiningTable" extends="Table">
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>

    <node name="MySummerHouse">
        <node name="DiningRoom">
            <node name="DiningTable" extends="Table">
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</nodeContainer>
```

In this document, nodes can "extend" other nodes that are :

- siblings
- siblings of parents

however, nodes should not "extend":

- parents
- children nodes of parent's siblings

This means that *MyHouse* can "extend" *Table*, which does not make sense, but I'm okay with that.

Also important is that both house nodes should be able to have their own nodes named *DiningRoom*.

And my current schema is similar to this:

```
<xs:complexType name="node">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="node"/> <!-- node can have other nodes inside it -->
        <xs:element ref="leaf"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="name"       type="xs:anySimpleType" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="extends"    type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- document root -->
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="nodeContainer">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element ref="node"/>    
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="otherType"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- create constrictions -->
    <xs:unique name="UniqueNodes">
        <xs:selector xpath="nodeContainer/node"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:keyref refer="UniqueNodes" name="ValidNodeExtends">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//node"></xs:selector>
        <xs:field xpath="@extends"></xs:field>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

This schema does part of what I'm looking for. It sets the keys to be the names of the first level of nodes in *nodeContainer*, and those keys can be used to "extend" any node at any level at or below *nodeContainer*. And that works as long as I don't want to "extend" siblings at lower levels. The example document above does not validate because of this line:

```
<node name="DiningRoom" extends="RoomWithDoor">
```

In the schema I've created *RoomWithDoor* is not a valid key to assign to "extends" since it's not part of the first level of nodes in *nodeContainer*. But is there anyway to write the keys/keyrefs to make them valid keys? Does placement of the keys/keyref definitions make a difference? Are my xpaths too specific (how can they be less specific)?

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you change the XPath selector for UniqueNodes to

```
<xs:selector xpath="nodeContainer//node"/>
```

In other words - any node element under the nodeContainer.
Would not this allow what you want to achieve?